# iOS Random Numbers in a range

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, arc4random

I know I can get a random number for example from 0 to 700 using:

```
arc4random() % 362
```

But how can I get a random number in between for example 200 to 300?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(arc4random() % 100) + 200

Answer (score 1):

Not to be picky, but I am pretty sure you have to add a number...
if you want all the numbers from 200 to and including 300... use

```
200 + arc4random()%101;
```

`arc4random()%100`   would give a random number from 0 to 99   so 300 would never occur...