# Random number in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)
>   [iOS Random Numbers in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059049/ios-random-numbers-in-a-range)
>   [Generate non-repeating, no sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612784/generate-non-repeating-no-sequential-numbers)

I am looking for method that give me random numbers between two numbers, and the first number will be number that I choose between the numbers.

for example, if I give this random function 5 and 10 and 9 as the first number, so it will give me: 9,10,7,6,5,8

I tried to use it:

```
NSUInteger count = [array count];
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    while (n==`firstnumber`) {
        n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: just assign the first one yourself and generate the rest of the random numbers. No need for a while loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Comment: If the expected output is always same then how could it be random number? May be I missed something in the question.

Comment: its not the same, i gave an example,the first number is set by me and the other numbers by the method ,and every number is shown only one time.

Comment: It looks like you're basically after something that shuffles.  See the [tag:shuffle] tag for some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first number is set by me and the other numbers by the method ,and
>   every number is shown only one time

It looks like you are after a shuffling algorithm. The following category on `NSMutableArray` will do the job:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Shuffling)
- (void)shuffle;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle
{
    // Fisher–Yates shuffle (modern algorithm)
    // To shuffle an array a of n elements (indexes 0..n-1):
    // for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
    //     j <-- random integer with 0 <= j <= i
    //     exchange a[j] and a[i]
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

    for (int i = [self count] - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        int j = arc4random() % (i + 1);
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

@end
```

Your requirement is that the number in the first position of the array is fixed (given by you). Then, you can do something like this:

1. Populate the array with all numbers between `minValue` and `maxValue` (both included) except for `firstValue`.
2. Shuffle the array.
3. Insert `firstValue` at the first position in the array.

Resulting in the following code:

```
NSInteger minValue = 5;
NSInteger maxValue = 10;
NSInteger firstValue = 9;

// minValue <= firstValue <= maxValue

// populate the array with all numbers between minValue 
// and maxValue (both included) except for firstValue
NSMutableArray *ary = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = minValue; i < firstValue; i++) {
    [ary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
for (int i = firstValue + 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    [ary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
// --> (5,6,7,8,10)
// shuffle the array using the category method above
[ary shuffle];
// insert firstValue at the first position in the array
[ary insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:firstValue] atIndex:0];
// --> (9,x,x,x,x,x)
```

Answer (score 4):

`int r = arc4random() % 9 + 5` will give you numbers between 5 and 13 including both of them.

Comment: Why would someone downrate this? It's the best possible answer.

Comment: @Alex K.: Same thing I also want to know as it's a puzzle for me...Thanks for your concern.